# AWS Cognito: getting "Please provide a valid public provider" with google

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, oauth, google-plus, amazon-cognito

I'm getting 400 "Please provide a valid public provider" when I try to set the google access token like this:

```
AWS.config.update(
{
    region: window.region,
    credentials: new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials(
    {
        IdentityPoolId: window.identityPoolId,
        Logins:
        {
            'accounts.google.com': gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().currentUser.get().getAuthResponse().id_token
        }
    })
});
```

Cognito is inited like this:

```
window.region = Pointer_stringify(region);
window.identityPoolId = 'us-east-1:xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx';
var po = document.createElement('script');
po.type = 'text/javascript';
po.async = true;
po.src = '/aws-sdk.min.js';
po.onload = function()
{
    var po2 = document.createElement('script');
    po2.type = 'text/javascript';
    po2.async = true;
    po2.src = '/amazon-cognito.min.js';
    po2.onload = function()
    {
        AWS.config.region = window.region; // Region
        AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials(
        {
            IdentityPoolId: window.identityPoolId,
        });
    }
    var s2 = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s2.parentNode.insertBefore(po2, s2);
}
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
```

I have the google client id added to the Google+ tab of Authention providers and accounts.google.com added to OpenID tab.
This only happens with Google, it works with Facebook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was that my Identity Pool pointed to a deleted user pool.

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons you may see this errors is if you have configured your pool for developer authenticated flow with the provider name being 'accounts.google.com'. Could you check in Cognito Console for Custom Authentication Providers in your pool and ensure that it's not set to 'accounts.google.com'?